# How to properly initialize time with localtime in c++?

Tags: c++, datetime, localtime

I am getting the beginning of Epoch, where I should get current time:

*date.hpp*:

```
#ifndef DATE_HPP
#define DATE_HPP

#include <time.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>

class Date
{
    std::stringstream format;
    struct tm *date_tm;
    time_t date;

public:
    Date() : date(time(NULL)), date_tm(localtime(&date)) {}
    Date(std::istream &in);
    Date(std::string str);

    const std::string getDate();
};

#endif //DATE_HPP
```

*date.cpp*:

```
#include "date.hpp"
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <iomanip>

Date::Date(std::istream &in)
{
    std::cout << "enter date [mm/dd/yy]: ";
    format.basic_ios::rdbuf(in.rdbuf());
    format >> std::get_time(date_tm, "%m/%d/%y");
}

Date::Date(std::string str)
{
    format << str;
    format >> std::get_time(date_tm, "%m/%d/%y");
}

const std::string Date::getDate()
{
    format << std::put_time(date_tm, "%m/%d/%y");
    return format.str();
}
```

*main.cpp*:

```
#include "date.hpp"
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    Date now;
    std::cout << now.getDate() << std::endl;
}
```

When I run it `./a.out`, I get `01/01/70`. Well obviously, I would expect current time, since the `time(NULL)` which is used in `localtime(now)`, should contain seconds from Epoch *till* now. So what could went wrong?

Comment: Turn on your compiler warnings. In addition, your class will break if multiple instances are created because `localtime` essentially gives back a pointer to a global.

Comment: Consider `struct tm date_tm;` (no `*`) and `*date_tm(localtime(&date)`  (Added `*`)

Comment: C++ has [`chrono`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono) which is way, way better than `time(NULL)`.

Comment: Perhaps `date(time(NULL)), date_tm(localtime(&date))` is not sequentially evaluated?

Comment: And isn't compiler required to evaluate to the default ctor sequentially?

Comment: Side note: you really don't want the default constructor of Date to give you the now moment, it's a hidden performance issue. Better to make it a static method

Comment: @JVApen I do not get it. Why

Comment: For example if you use it as a value in std::map with operator[] it will call this default constructor before assigning your new value. (Oh, and it's a pain to fix this later, I have experience with that)

Answer (score 1):

Aside from the defects mentioned in the comments (`localtime()` returns a pointer to a global) you're running into a construction order issue.

In your class, `date_tm` is constructed/initialized *before* `date`, regardless of their order in the initialization list.

Change your class definition to see the results you expect:

```
class Date
{
    std::stringstream format;
    time_t date;        // ensure date is constructed/initialized before date_tm
    struct tm *date_tm;

    // ...
}
```

(see:  https://ideone.com/FRJrdB)

As stated in the comments, the compiler should warn you about this if you have the proper warning levels enabled.

Comment: what is "pointer to global", how it differs to "pointer to local"?

Comment: I thought, having pointer declared *inside* of class declaration, would not make it global

Comment: @milanHrabos, The global thing is the object being pointed to by the return value of `localtime`, and hence pointed to by your class member as well. Calling `localtime` twice (or a few other functions that share that state) can overwrite the object while you're still pointing to it and return the same pointer instead of returning a pointer to a new object. If it helps, you can think of the `localtime` implementation as something like `tm g_state; tm* localtime(const time_t* t) { g_state = calculate_local_time(t); return &g_state; }`